# How to check if device gives consent for sharing data with Meta SKAdNetwork?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ads, skadnetwork

To use `SKAdNetwork` I need to set flag `isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` either to true or to false.

In Facebook documentation they say to set it according the device consent:

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled/

How can I check if device gives consent for this or not? What is the permission I need to look for or ask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947972/can-we-check-if-allow-apps-to-request-to-track-toggle-is-on

Comment: @CBroe That is Ad Tracking Permission, that is different. Even if user disabled Ad Tracking, we can still use SKAdNetwork. That's the benefit of it

Comment: What exactly is different here, in your opinion? _"Even if user disabled Ad Tracking, we can still use SKAdNetwork."_ - I don't see what that changes, in regard to your app having to set `isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled`?

Comment: @CBroe I am asking what is the case when I need to set `isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false`

Comment: Well exactly then, when the documentation says: _"If a device provides consent, call the setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled method of the FBSDKSettings class and set it to YES for Objective-C or true for Swift. If a device does **not allow tracking**, set setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled **to NO** for Objective-C or **false** for Swift. "_

Comment: The reason why Meta doesn't describe this in greater detail is because of all the overly complicated legal fuss on user privacy. Thus they want to make the developer accountable for how they use their tracking tools. I'm pretty sure the way Apple defines "tracking" and the way Meta does it are a little different; but yeah, for most cases setting Meta's tracking consent flag in accordance to the user's Apple App Tracking Transparency consent will be alright, if not the most correct decision.